# Firebase Auth - no email from google sign in provider

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Email is null when signing in with Google provider

I have tried with 3 Gmail accounts - 1 of them is OK, but with 2 I get null.
All three are listed in the console properly with the account's Email as "Identifier"

```
 currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 String Email = currentUser.getEmail();
```

code creating auth:

```
providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()
 );

 startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                        .build(),MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Please post the code for google sign in.

Comment: added above  @Juanje

Comment: Do you try the normal way without the new UI method?

Comment: Are you using "multiple accounts per email" setting in the Firebase Console? Also did you check the email in the `user.getProviderData()` list?

Comment: No, @Juanje, i used the new method.

Comment: @bojeil - no. it didn't show under user.getProviderData()

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem. Enabled multiple accounts per email. There are 2 accounts with the same email. `currentUser` shows null for email as well as in the `providerData` when logging in via Google.

Comment: Found it! There are 2 entries in `providerData` and the second contains the email address. First providerId == null, the second providerId == 'google.com' and that entry has the email address

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, no Google email address was returned.

After adding the scope email:

```
var provider = new this.$firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('email');
```

it was returning the email address in the providerdata.

The same problem I had also with Facebook login. I needed to add the scope like this

```
var provider = new this.$firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.addScope("email");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, I had the same issue, but on applying `GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(LoginActivity.this);` after authentication with firebase, the issue got resolved.

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            String a="Email: "+user.getEmail()
                                    +"\nName: "+user.getDisplayName()+"\nL= "+user.getProviderData();   
                        //Here I got email field as null: 1 of them is OK, but with remaining I get null
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: USER DATA:\n"+a);

        // Add this code to get current sign-in user info 
                            GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(LoginActivity.this);
                            if (acct != null) {
                                String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
                                String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
                                String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
                                String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
                                String personId = acct.getId();
                                Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: RESULT--> "+"Name: "+personName+"\n"+
                                        "Email: "+personEmail+"\n"+
                                        "ID: "+personId+"\n"+
                                        "Photo: "+personPhoto+"\n"+
                                        "PersonGiven Name: "+personGivenName+"\n");
                            }



//                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Snackbar.make(r, "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just disabled multiple accounts from the firebase settings option. Now I am getting the email.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I can see that <currentUser.providerData> contains two lists.
After comparison, the 0th list had no email value, but contained displayName and photoUrl. The first list had all three values. So I'm using the first value. But I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I copied the code from the testing project to my main project and the problem is resolved. I don't understand why.